# Synchronization of two databases using Services on Windows

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services

I have Windows application which should work in offline mode. When the network is up the data should be moved to centralized server. The data should be synchronized, and same SQL Server database would be used by web application so the sync needs to be **bi-directional**.

I was thinking of using a Windows service for this. Can this be done? Any code or guidelines on how to start would be appreciated.

Comment: forgot to mention,i am using ms-sql database

Comment: Why is this being flagged for closure?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) or the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx).

Comment: i already know about server replication and sync framework..but that is not what i was looking,i want it to be done in windows services only.can it be done.

Comment: You can use these technologies from inside a Windows service.